# rails 3,Kaminari pagination for an simple Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

For paginating a common array I got this solution,

> @arr_name =
>   Kaminari.paginate_array(@arr_name).page(params[:page]).per(PER_PAGE_RECORDS)

`PER_PAGE_RECORDS` is a variable with value as per needed for pagination.

Any better Ideas??

Also to have an ajax call for using pagination one can use this,

In your view,

give id to your div tab

```
div id="paginate"
```

and inside it

> <%= paginate @arr_name, :remote => true  %>

And in js response file put,

> $('#paginate').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@arr_name, :remote
>   => true).to_s) %>');

So your requests will be AJAX.

Thanks.

Comment: Please format your code using 4-space indentation or backticks. Thank you.

Comment: what exactly is your problem ?

Comment: @Fivell He's not sure if this is the correct approach?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This is the only available helper method to paginate an array object using Kaminari. Another alternative is, as suggested solution in [kaminari wiki page](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/Kaminari-recipes), add the instance methods to the array object.

If you are trying a common solution based on the ActiveModel return type ( .all returns array and .where returns ARL) then following is an workaround.

```
unless @arr_name.kind_of?(Array)
  @arr_name = @arr_name.page(params[:page]).per(PER_PAGE_RECORDS)
else
  @arr_name = Kaminari.paginate_array(@arr_name).page(params[:page]).per(PER_PAGE_RECORDS)
end
```

Comment: Nice solution. Just a little suggestion @Sethupathi. It is a best practice to use 'if else' instead of 'unless else' :) Cheers!